# MATLAB: Solve system of linear equalities while constraining some values to be positive

Tags: matlab

A [paper I'm reading](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i90nfv3maepo7vh/Davis-Stober%20et%20al%202015.pdf?dl=0) contains the following theorem.

[image: Theorem 2]

I wrote some MATLAB code to try and reproduce results that appear later in the paper, and initially it seemed to work well.

```
M = 6;

Sigma = [1 .5 .15 .15 0 0;
 .5 1 .15 .15 0 0;
 .15 .15 1 .25 0 0;
 .15 .15 .25 1 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 1 .1;
 0 0 0 0 .1 1];

Delta = [0 0 .2 .2 .5 .5]';

cov_vect = [.3 .3 .35 .35 .25 .25];

u = ones(M,1);

lastcol = [u' 0];

First = Sigma+(Delta*Delta');
First(M+1,:) = u;
First(:,M+1) = lastcol;

Third = [cov_vect 1]';

X = linsolve(First,Third);
```

This code creates results that match those from the paper.

I want to use my code with other data sets, but when I try to do that I encounter a problem. M, Sigma, Delta, and cov_vect will vary from data set to data set, but the rest of the code should stay the same.

When I use my code on new data sets, then although the vector w sums to 1 (as it should) it sometimes contains negative values. According to the paper, this shouldn't happen. It's fine for lambda to be negative, but none of the values in the w vector can be negative.

How can I get MATLAB to constrain the results so that all the values in w must be positive, while maintaining the requirement that the vector w sum to 1?

Comment: One idea: you could formulate your problem as an optimization problem. Eg. minimize x'*A*x + b'*x subject to C * x <= 0 or whatever. Matlab has several tools for efficiently solving linear or quadratic optimization problems (and indeed others). Eg. [quadprog](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) or [linprog](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html).

Comment: Looking through the documentation for linprog, it seems like I should have something like [X,FVAL] = linprog(f,First,Third). But what is f in this context?

Comment: To get that system of linear equalities, did the paper authors solve some optimization problem? First thing I'd do (if possible) is solve same optimization problem with added constraint that w is non-negative.

Comment: Try taking a look at `lsqnonneg`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lsqnonneg.html - This determines the best solution to a least squares problem ensuring that the solution is all positive.  Something worth considering.

Comment: I got kinda curious, so I just did it. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question appears to reference [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276269014_The_Composition_of_Optimally_Wise_Crowds).

Theorem 2 you reference is the solution to the following optimization problem (see error/typos section, I've had to make at least one correction).

```
minimize (over w)  w' * (Sigma + delta * delta') * w - 2 * cov_vect' * w

                                      subject to:  w'*ones(n, 1) = 1
```

#### This can be solved using Matlab function [quadprog](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html?refresh=true) with:

```
H = 2 * (Sigma + delta * Delta');  % see quadprog docs, it solves 1/2 so we need 2
f = - 2 * cov_vect;
A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = ones(1,6);
beq = 1;
w = quadprog(H, f, A, b, Aeq, beq);
```

You can add the lower bound constraint of 0 with:

```
lb = zeros(6, 1);
ub = [];
w2 = quadprog(H, f, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub);
```

#### How to solve this in [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) (awesome optimization package)

```
cvx_begin
variables y(n);
minimize(y' * (Sigma + Delta * Delta') * y - 2 * cov_vect * y)
subject to:
   y'*ones(n,1) == 1;
   y >= 0;
cvx_end
```

Link to [cvx](http://cvxr.com/cvx/).

#### Typo in appendix of paper as posted on researchgate:

(typo) Their proof of theorem 2 omits the `2*w` in term 2*cov_vect' * w of thier objective function. [The minimization problem *should be*](http://www.mattgunn.com/comment/davis_stober_2015/objective.pdf):

```
minimize (over w)  w' * (Sigma + delta * delta') * w - 2*cov_vect' * w
```

Which indeed gives solution:

```
0.1596    0.1596    0.2090    0.2090    0.1314    0.1314
```

Or equivalently:

```
minimize (over w)  .5 * w' * (Sigma + delta * delta') * w - cov_vect' * w
```

Comment: How did you work out that the version with the .5 in front would work? Using CVX I was able to independently verify putting the .5 in front allows the re-creation of their results, but I don't how you discovered that it would work.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have a published version of the paper? or just the researchgate version? I'm curious if the objective function in the appendix of the published version is corrected/different. I'm not so curious though to pay $30 :P

Comment: @user1205901 How did I figure out the .5? I just guessed since it seemed like an easy mistake to make (I may have called quadprog without a 2* in front of A while coding it myself). I don't know: is proper objective `w'(S+d*d')w - 2 *cov_vect'*w`? or is it `w'(S+d*d')w - cov_vect'*w`. I don't know! Maybe published paper is different, maybe typo in appendix, maybe appendix is right and small error in paper. Quite possible everything is right and just appendix has a typo in researchgate posted version. I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks. I attached a published version in the first line of the question.

Comment: @user1205901 The typo is in Appendix A. Their published numbers in the solution are correct. I will edit my answer.

Comment: In Appendix A they say that they're minimizing a function of w, rather than w itself. Does that offer some scope for Appendix A to be correct, and to not have a typo?

Comment: The answer in their paper is correct. It is the appendix which has the incorrect objective. Looks like a minor typo. See Derivation of correct objective [here](http://www.mattgunn.com/comment/davis_stober_2015/objective.pdf)

Comment: The authors note that the optimal set of weights is unique iff the first matrix in the system is non-singular. When I apply this system to actual data the first matrix in the system is singular and therefore there are multiple sets of optimal weights. Is it possible to configure CVX so that I can see more than just one solution?